# How to compute histogram using three variables in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, histogram, matlab-figure

I have three variables, e.g., latitude, longitude and temperature. For each latitude and longitude, I have corresponding temperature value. I want to plot latitude v/s longitude plot in 5 degree x 5 degree grid , with mean temperature value inserted in that particular grid instead of occurring frequency.

```
Data= [latGrid,lonGrid] = meshgrid(25:45,125:145);  
T = table(latGrid(:),lonGrid(:),randi([0,35],size(latGrid(:))),...  
   'VariableNames',{'lat','lon','temp'});
```

At the end, I need it somewhat like the following image:

[image]

Comment: Please see: [mcve]

Comment: I don't if it'll help but try looking https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcolor.html

Comment: Something like [`bar3`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar3.html)?

Comment: ya but I want a 2d plot at the end

Comment: Do you have data for every grid point (degree of lat/long)? Do you have the Image Processing Toolbox? I have to say that deleting your previous question and replacing it with one that includes even less information was counterproductive.

Comment: @beaker- I am sorry for deleting previous post, as I felt the information was not enough. I don't have Image Processing tool. I have also added the data .

Comment: Are your measurements taken at the same lat/long intervals? For example, is there always n degrees between each temperature measurement? If so, my answer will work. Otherwise, please clarify your question.

Comment: The image that you added does not help us understand what is not working for you. Please answer beaker and my questions about whether you have measurements at evenly spaced degree intervals points.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like you want to scale your grid. The easiest way to do this is to smooth and downsample.

While 2d histograms also bin values into a grid, using a histogram is not the way to find the mean of datapoints in a smooth grid. A histogram counts the occurrence of values in a set of ranges. In a 2d example, a histogram would take the input measurements [1, 3, 3, 5] and count the number of ones, the number of threes, etc. A 2d histogram will count occurrences of pairs of numbers. (You might want to use histogram to help organize a measurements taken at irregular intervals, but that would be a different question)

### How to smooth and downsample without the Image Processing Toolbox

Keep your data in the 2d matrix format rather than reshaping it into a table. This makes it easier to find the neighbors of each grid location.

```
%% Sample Data 
[latGrid,lonGrid] = meshgrid(25:45,125:145);
temp = rand(size(latGrid));
```

There are many tools in Matlab for smoothing matrices. If you want to have the mean of a 5x5 window. You can write a for-loop, use a convolution, or use [`filter2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter2.html?searchHighlight=filter2&s_tid=doc_srchtitle). My example uses convolution. For more on convolutional filters, I suggest [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)).

```
%% Mean filter with conv2 
M = ones(5) ./ 25; % 5x5 mean or box blur filter
C_temp = conv2(temp, M, 'valid');
```

`C_temp` is a blurry version of the original temperature variable with a slightly smaller size because we can't accurately take the mean of the edges. The border is reduced by a frame of 2 measurements. Now, we just need to take every fifth measurement from `C_temp` to scale down the grid.

```
%% Subsample result
C_temp = C_temp(1:5:end, 1:5:end);

% Because we removed a border from C_temp, we also need to remove a border from latGrid and lonGrid
[h, w] = size(latGrid) 
latGrid = latGrid(5:5:h-5, 5:5:w-5);
lonGrid = lonGrid(5:5:h-5, 5:5,w-5);
```

Here's what the steps look like

[image: Smooth and Downsample Steps]

If you use a slightly more organized, `temp` variable. It's easier to see that the result is correct.

[image: Smooth and Downsample Identity Matrix]

### With Image Processing Toolbox

[`imresize`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html?s_tid=doc_ta#inputarg_method) has a box filter method option that is equivalent to a mean filter. However, you have to do a little calculation to find the scaling factor that is equivalent to using a 5x5 window.

```
C_temp = imresize(temp, scale, 'box');
```